# Error while accessing array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm getting the error

> Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2

near the bottom of the code. I'm not sure why. I'm trying to build a set of arrays to manipulate but I'm getting hung up at this point.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Initialize ();

    while (true) {
        SystemEvents.CheckEvents ();
        Update ();
        Render ();
    }
}

public static void Initialize ()
{
    // Set up the graphics system
    graphics = new GraphicsContext ();

    gen = new Random ();
    Texture2D pTex= new Texture2D("Application/assets/plane.png",false);
    player= new Sprite(graphics,pTex);

    player.Position.X = graphics.Screen.Rectangle.Width / 2 - player.Width / 2;
    player.Position.Y = graphics.Screen.Rectangle.Height / 2 - player.Height / 2;

    xpos = 0;
    ypos = 0;

    pieces = new Texture2D[6];

    bg = new Sprite[9,12];

    pattern = new int[9,12];

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        pieces [i] = new Texture2D ("Application/assets/island" + i + ".png", false);

    for(int i=0; i< pattern.Length; i++)
        pattern[i] = gen.Next(0,5);      // Problem is here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pattern` is a *two-dimensional* array. So you need to provide two indices to access it's values.

If you want to populate `pattern` with random values you can use two for loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i<pattern.GetLength(0); i++) 
{
     for(int j=0; j<pattern.GetLength(1); j++)
     {
          pattern[i,j] = gen.Next(0,5);
     }
}
```

**Further Reading**

- [Multidimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://tr.tribalwars2.com/game.php?world=tr1&character_id=13241#/)
- [Array.GetLength Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't even see a declaration for `pattern`. But judging from the assignment `pattern = new int[9,12];`, it must be a two-dimensional array. So to access an element in it, you need to specify two different indexes.

What kind of array do you think that `new int[9,12];` creates?

Comment: new int[9,12] => Creates an two dimensional array with 9 rows and columns 12 in a table

Comment: @AjayTakur: that's what it does. But it's not clear that's what the OP _thinks_ it does.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for the bad copy and paste job. It's my first post on here and I'm new to programming. Yes, I understand that it creates am array of 9 rows and 12 columns. What I don't know is why it's giving me a wrong number of indices error near the bottom.

Comment: How many indexes do you believe you need to provide, when accessing an element in a two-dimensional array? And if that number is something other than two, why do you believe that?